# Swift - Pass data from table view xib file to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I am trying to pass data from my table which is a xib file to a view controller but for some reason, the code is not working and throwing an error. I have also browsed the internet, yet not got the solution.

**viewDidLoad Function**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataPass()
       self.navigationItem.title = "Landlord List"
        propertyTabel.register(UINib(nibName: "PropertyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        propertyTabel.dataSource = self
        propertyTabel.delegate = self
   }
```

**didSelectRowAt Function**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PropertyDetailsVC") as? PropertyDetailsVC
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        prop.userId = nullToNil(value: dict["user_id"]) as? String
        prop.id = nullToNil(value: dict["property_id"]) as? String
        prop.code = nullToNil(value: dict["property_code"]) as? String      
        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what is prop.id in above code?

Comment: you are using storyboard or xib?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @Nilesh prop is the object of model class PropertyList

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad I am using both xib and storyboard wherever required

Comment: @Scriptable Attached error screenshot in question

Comment: Check your Storyboard Identifier for PropertyDetailsVC.

Comment: @Rocky I doubled checked it. The identifier name is correct.

Comment: `storyboard?` got nil so that `vc` got nil too, your force unwrapped a nil object then your app crashed. Instead, you have to explicitly use `UIStoryboard.init(name: "MainOrSomethingElse", bundle: nil)`

Comment: @Saurabh - Ok, then if you have different storyboard for controllers then create the object of storyboard with specific name. e.g. `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: NAME, bundle: BUNDLE) `

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your `didSelect` method

```
let yourStoryboardObject = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)

let vc = yourStoryboardObject?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PropertyDetailsVC") as? PropertyDetailsVC
```

Comment: Ok...I will give it a try

Comment: Thanks for your answer.